# jQuery: Horizontal scroll-to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
// General Function

$("li a").click(function() {
  $("li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});


// Horizontal Scroll-to Function

$("li a").click(function() {
  var offset = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var left = offset.left;
  $("#nav").scrollLeft(left);
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#box {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#one" class="active">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="items">
    <div class="item" id="one">
      <div class="item-content">One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="two">
      <div class="item-content">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="three">
      <div class="item-content">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="four">
      <div class="item-content">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="five">
      <div class="item-content">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="six">
      <div class="item-content">Six</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Generally, it works how it should work. If you click link "**Two**", it's perfect. Also, if you scroll horizontally to link "**Six**", and click it, it's perfect. *Buuuut*: If you click for example link "**Four**" or link "**Five**", the behavior is pretty weird. After clicking on a link, the entire line of links should always be scrolled to the left, until the position of the `active` link. If it's not possible – for example for the last links – then it just should be scrolled as far as possible. And for example the last link should always stay on the right side.

I think it's necessary to get the left border of `offset.left`. But I don't know how to do that.

Can somebody help me please? Would be soooo thankful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) takes the scroll position into account:

> *The amount of scrolling that has been done [...] is taken into account when computing the bounding rectangle. This means that the rectangle's boundary edges (`top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`) change their values every time the scrolling position changes [...].*
>
> ***If you need the bounding rectangle relative to the top-left corner of the document, just add the current scrolling position to the top and left properties.***

So you can use the current `scrollLeft` position and add it:

```js
var $nav   = $('#nav'),
    $links = $('li a');

$links.click(function() {
  $links.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  var left       = this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      scrollLeft = $nav.scrollLeft();

  $nav.scrollLeft(left + scrollLeft);
});
```

```html
<!-- Unchanged HTML & CSS --> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="box"> <ul id="nav"> <li><a href="#one" class="active">One</a></li><li><a href="#two">Two</a></li><li><a href="#three">Three</a></li><li><a href="#four">Four</a></li><li><a href="#five">Five</a></li><li><a href="#six">Six</a></li></ul> <div id="items"> <div class="item" id="one"> <div class="item-content">One</div></div><div class="item" id="two"> <div class="item-content">Two</div></div><div class="item" id="three"> <div class="item-content">Three</div></div><div class="item" id="four"> <div class="item-content">Four</div></div><div class="item" id="five"> <div class="item-content">Five</div></div><div class="item" id="six"> <div class="item-content">Six</div></div></div><style>::-webkit-scrollbar{display: none;}*{-ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none; font-family: sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-size: 34px; color: inherit; text-decoration: none;}#box{background-color: grey; height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow-y: auto; scroll-behavior: smooth;}#nav{position: fixed; width: 300px; display: flex; white-space: nowrap; color: white; overflow-y: auto; z-index: 1; scroll-behavior: smooth;}li{margin-right: 30px;}.item{width: 100%; padding: 20px;}.item-content{height: 200px; background-color: darkgrey;}.active{background-color: black; left: 0;}</style>
```